# node app not working while mongodb is inserting

Tags: performance, node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert

I'm still learning mongodb and node.js.

I was trying to insert bulk amount of data say 100k rows with 80-100 columns. I created an app using express.js for that. I coded in such a a way that the page redirects to another page once upload button is clicked and in the background the app inserts the data into the db.

The issue is that once the inserting starts the app stops responding. Even after the completion of insert the app will be slower for about 2-3 minutes.

I tried this code on

1

- Fedora 14
- Intel P4 2.80GHz
- 1.5GiB

2

- Fedora 14
- i3 3.20GHz
- 3GiB

How to avoid this problem? Will it work better on a better system?

**Code to store the data**

```
MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
    var collection = database.collection(collectionName);
    for (index = 0; index < jsonResult.length; ++index) {
        var obj = jsonResult[index];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (headers[prop] == 'Date') {
                obj[prop] = new Date(obj[prop].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
            } else if (headers[prop] == 'Integer') {
                obj[prop] = parseInt(obj[prop]);
            } else if (headers[prop] == 'Float') {
                obj[prop] = parseFloat(obj[prop]);
            }
        }
        collection.insert(obj, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });    
    }
});
```

Note:

- jsonResult is the result of reading a file(csv) and converting it
  into json
- headers is an object that have the key-data type mapping

  var headers = {
      'iodate': 'date',
      'sno': 'integer',
      'salary': 'float'
  }

**Code to read and convert csv to json**

```
var cv_json = require('convert-json'); // required module convert-json (convert-csv,xls,xlsx into json)
cv_json({
    input: target_path,
    output: null
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        persists(req, res, result, collectionName, headers);  //Function where insert takes place.
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is `jsonResult` coming from? Is this the result of reading a file.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes by reading a csv file using module `convert-json`

Comment: Yeah. Can you include your code where you are reading the csv file and doing your transform. So people can see what you are striving for there. There is a better way to do this.

Comment: @NeilLunn Oh ok sure:)

Comment: @NeilLunn Updated the code with snippet used for csv to json conversion

Comment: Probably should have asked for a peek of the csv as well for completeness. Including a header line I suppose since you don't seem to be defining the columns anywhere else. Unless that code is missing.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't understand. This is the whole code, are you referring to `headers[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the "persists()" return imidiately, even though the insert hasn't finished. This is due to the asyncronus nature of javascript/nodejs.

You need to serialize the insert operations so you don't clog the server. Use async.eachSeries()

Your "persists" function should use a callback to notify the caller that it has finished. Somehing like this:

```
persists(req, res, result, collectionName, headers, callback){
    MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
        var collection = database.collection(collectionName);
        async.eachSeries(jsonResult, 
            function(obj, cb){
                for (var prop in obj) {
                    if (headers[prop] == 'Date') {
                        obj[prop] = new Date(obj[prop].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/,"$2/$1/$3"));
                    } else if (headers[prop] == 'Integer') {
                        obj[prop] = parseInt(obj[prop]);
                    } else if (headers[prop] == 'Float') {
                        obj[prop] = parseFloat(obj[prop]);
                    }
                }
                collection.insert(obj, function (err, result) {
                    cb(err);
                });                    
            }, 
            function(err){
                callback();
            }
        );
    });
}
```

And then to use it

```
persists(req, res, result, collectionName, headers, function(){
    console.log("insert finished");
});
```

Comment: Won't this wait for the function to end? I want the insert to run in the background without disturbing the app.

Comment: You mentioned you are using express.js so i assume you have a webapp. In that case, http calls are executed "concurently", due to the non-blocking nature of nodejs.

Comment: But still the app waits for insert to complete; to load another page.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your server code. Can you post it?

Comment: Which portion do you want?

Comment: I updated my answer, you have to user async.series . This has a callback that is executed when all the inserts are finished. If all the parallel inserts are slowing down your server, you can try async.eachSeries . This will serialize the inserts so the load on the server will be low

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49534/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-gtsouk)